# Проблема с Windows Forms

Tags: c#, while

Есть написанная мною программа на c# и в ней есть цикл while. Но когда я запускают программу с этим циклом, то нет того окна которое я сделал. Только вижу отладку Visual Studio.

Comment: У меня тоже есть программа с циклом, но там всё работает.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Вангую что он цикл влепил на запуске формы и пока цикл не отработает(или он вечный?) программа не хочет появлятся т.к. юай поток занят циклом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В любом случае, то что написано в Form1.cs выполняется в потоке UI и соответственно ты этим циклом не дашь выполниться методам отрисовки форму. Т.е. пока у тебя что-то выполняется в Form1.cs форма у тебя будет не перемещаемая и не отвечать на любые взаимодействия с ней. Исходя  из того, что форма у тебя не хочет появляться, то цикл у тебя как минимум около бесконечный. Используй другой поток или async/await.

Comment: _то что написано в Form1.cs выполняется в потоке UI_ - ничего подобного. Form1.cs - это всего лишь файл. А написан в нем может быть абсолютно любой код. Который может выполняться в любых потоках.